# How do i maintain a user cover uploaded image in fields whiles adding new images without it getting deleted in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

How do i get Django to store already uploaded cover image to a user without getting it deleted when a new image is uploaded, but simply replace it? I'm having a challenge trying to figure out how to maintain old cover images while adding new once to a user. what happens is that when i upload a new cover image it simply deletes the previous one from the database.
Here is my cover image models:

```
class AccountCover(models.Model):
    account = models.ForeignKey(Account,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    cover_image = models.ImageField(max_length=255,upload_to=get_cover_cover_image_filepath,default=get_default_cover_image,)
```

Here the view to upload cover image

```
 cover = AccountCover.objects.filter(account=account.id).first()
    if request.user:
        forms = CoverImageForm(request.POST, request.FILES,instance=cover,
                        initial = {'cover_image':cover.cover_image})
      
    if request.method == 'POST':
        f = CoverImageForm(request.POST, request.FILES,instance=cover)
        if f.is_valid():
             data = forms.save()
             data.account = cover.account
             data.save()
             return redirect('account:edit', account.id)
            
    else:
        f = CoverImageForm()
    context['f'] = f
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest adding a field called `historical` which is a `boolean field` in your class. Then, when a new image is uploaded you have to set `historical=False` and `historical=True` for all others. You can achieve this with:

```
 cover = AccountCover.objects.filter(account=account.id).first()
    if request.user:
        forms = CoverImageForm(request.POST, request.FILES,instance=cover,
                        initial = {'cover_image':cover.cover_image})
      
    if request.method == 'POST':
        f = CoverImageForm(request.POST, request.FILES,instance=cover)
        if f.is_valid():
             data = forms.save()
             data.account = cover.account
             cover.historical=True
             data.historical= False
             data.save()
             cover.save()
             return redirect('account:edit', account.id)
            
    else:
        f = CoverImageForm()
    context['f'] = f
```

Comment: Thank you for your time , But your solution didn't work in my case since the cover images still get deleted and replace when a new one is uploaded.